# JQgrid: Two linked select dropdowns

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Can someone point me to an example whet I can have 2 select boxes in a grid and by selecting an item in one box, sends a request back to the server to get the other items for the second select box. Like one is linked to another.

Is there a onSelect or onChange that I can fires off after selecting the first selectbox?

Thanks in advance.

Scot..

Answer (score 0):

You should use dataEvents feature of the editoptions option of colModel (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editoptions). Set type:'change'. More details you will find in http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/dynamically-populate-select-dropdown/